# Can you specify a return type (especially a void return type) for a functor in a concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I do a lot of work with higher-order functions or templates that modify functions in C++

A pattern that's often useful is a function-modifier. For example, I use this simple wallclock benchmark quite a lot:

```
#include <chrono>
template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock, typename... Args>
auto wallclock(const auto& f, Args&... a){
    auto start = Clock::now();
    auto ret = f(a...);
    return std::make_tuple(ret,(std::chrono::duration<std::ratio<1,Unit>(Clock::now() - start).count());
}
```

This keeps even arguments-by-reference intact, and profiles the function nicely.

However, this invocation doesn't work with void functions, and I end up having to write a function with a different name to call for them, like so:

```
#include <chrono>
template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock, typename... Args>
auto wallclock_but_void(const auto& f, Args&... a){
    auto start = Clock::now();
    return f(a...), (std::chrono::duration<std::ratio<1,Unit>(Clock::now() - start).count();
}
```

I guess this is okay, but there are more complicated cases where it gets annoying. I'm wondering if there's a good way to specialize a function or template based on the return type of an arbitrary callable, so that the interface can be the same, and I keep thinking maybe I could do it with concepts. Like maybe

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
concept vreturn = requires(F&& f, Args&... a){
    { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(a)...) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
concept nvreturn = !vreturn<F, Args...>;

template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock, typename... Args>
auto wallclock(const auto& f, Args&... a) requires vreturn<decltype(f), Args...> {
    auto start = Clock::now();
    return f(a...), (Clock::now() - start).count();
}

template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock, typename... Args>
auto wallclock(const auto& f, Args&... a) requires (!vreturn<decltype(f), Args...>) {
    auto start = Clock::now();
    auto ret = f(a...);
    return std::make_tuple(ret, (Clock::now() - start).count());
}
```

But this nonetheless pattern-matches to the non-void version even when I call it with a void function. I'm not sure how I can get the behavior I want, but I feel like it has to be possible

**EDIT: (Min reproducible example)**

Because someone asked, the code that failed was (With the above definitions in place)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
void plusassign(int a, int b, int& x){
    x = a + b;
}

int plus(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int main(int, char**){
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine dre;
    dre.seed(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,0xFFFFFFFF);
    int a = dist(dre)
      , b = dist(dre)
      , x;
    auto t = wallclock(plusassign, a, b, x);
    std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << x << " (" << t << "ns)\n";
    auto [c, t2] = wallclock(plus, a, b);
    std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << " (" << t2 << "ns)\n";
    return 1;
}
```

This gave me a compiler error with g++ 11.2.0 (That "auto ret" invalidly assigned a void result)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, please show a [mre] using this code which fails. https://godbolt.org/z/1nPhbqq5a

Comment: Edited with minimal example

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is simply that you are not correctly forwarding arguments. Replace `Args&` with `Args&&` everywhere and also replace `a...` with `std::forward<Args>(a)...`. Then it will work as expected.

With just `Args&` you are never deducing the value category for `Args` and `std::invoke` will always try to call the callable with a rvalue, which fails if a function parameter is non-const lvalue reference.

Also, I would suggest to be consistent and also use `std::invoke` in the function definitions, given that you use it in the concept. `std::invoke` allows more forms of function calls than a simple call expression.

Comment: That's quite cool actually, I should better familiarize myself with move syntax. Thanks

Comment: @Advael Note that I missed one point where forwarding is necessary, see edited answer.

Comment: @Advael When used with a template-deduced argument, `&&` isn't an rvalue ("move syntax"), it's actually a deduced reference based on the input (referred to as a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references)).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using concept, you can just simply use `if constexpr` in the function body to determine whether the return type of the callable is `void`, and return the appropriate type.

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>

template<size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock, 
         typename F, typename... Args>
auto wallclock(const F& f, Args&... a) {
  auto start = Clock::now();
  if constexpr (std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<const F&, Args&...>, void>)
    return f(a...), (Clock::now() - start).count();
  else
    return std::make_tuple(f(a...), (Clock::now() - start).count());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sz4WqTqc7)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, and it's super weird to me that this works:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
concept vreturn = requires(F&& f, Args&... a){
    { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(a)...) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
concept nvreturn = !vreturn<F, Args...>;

template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock>
auto wallclock(const auto& f) requires vreturn<decltype(f)> {
    auto start = Clock::now();
    return f(), (Clock::now() - start).count();
}

template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock, typename... Args>
auto wallclock(const auto& f, Args&... a) requires vreturn<decltype(f), Args...> {
    return wallclock([&](){ f(a...); });
}

template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock>
auto wallclock(const auto& f) requires (!vreturn<decltype(f)>) {
    auto start = Clock::now();
    auto ret = f();
    return std::make_tuple(ret, (Clock::now() - start).count());
}

template <size_t Unit = 1000, class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock, typename... Args>
auto wallclock(const auto& f, Args&... a) requires (!vreturn<decltype(f), Args...>) {
    return wallclock([&](){ return f(a...); });
}
```

This will correctly pattern-match void versus non-void functions... but why tho?

Comment: In many functions I end up profiling (and want to combine in more complicated ways) some arguments are passed by reference, so I do want to cover cases where some of Args... could be passed by reference

Comment: I'm not sure I grok how I could use that in the general case. Could you give an example?